# How can I open a Canadian bank account from within the US? I am a Canadian citizen residing in the US

Tags: united-states, canada, bank-account, international-transfer, online-banking

Can I open a Canadian bank account from within the US?

I am Canadian citizen residing in the US for many years.  I would rather not travel to Canada just to open a bank account if possible.

- Does anyone know if I can open an account online without having to
  present ID in person at a later date?
- Or, if there are any alternatives that are acceptable for providing the required documentation other than in person at a branch?
- I would really like to be able to walk into a bank in the US and
  present my Canadian ID and have an account opened that deposits can
  be made into this    account from within Canada.

I don't know what problems this may create on either side of the boarder, but what I can gather from the internet is that my address in the US may prevent me from opening a Canadian account. Does anyone know if this is true?  Just looking for accurate information to rely upon. I do have a SIN and Canadian passport, but a US address. What name does TD bank in Canada operate under in the USA?

Comment: Do you have a Canadian address? I know TD has probably the most branches of any Canadian bank in the States. Have you walked in and checked with them? Do you have a Canadian SIN ?

Comment: Does a P.O. Box count as a Canadian address? Yes I have a Canadian SIN.  There is no TD branch in my city or within a few hundred miles that I can walk into.  Any suggestions?

Comment: HSBC will do it. You need an advanced account, and then you can view in global view and transfer money between your US and Canadian accounts. Let me know if they really opened an account for you in canada, as I am trying to do the same thing now. I am an EU citizen, and have no Canadian address nor SIN.